# Why does the concatenation of the empty set with any language give the empty set?

Tags: formal-languages, closure-properties

Why does the concatenation of $\emptyset$ with any language give $\emptyset$. I would like to know the intuitive explanation for it.

Comment: Just apply the definition.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Let $L_1, L_2$ be languages, then the concatenation $L_1\circ L_2=\{w\mid w=xy, x\in L_1, y\in L_2\}$. If $L_2=\varnothing$, then there is no string $y\in L_2$ and so there is no possible $w$ such that $w=xy$. Thus for any $L_1$, we'll have $L_1\circ\varnothing = \varnothing$.

Comment: ...because the concatenation of strings is a *binary* operator, and if $L_{2}$ is empty, then $y$ will not be the empty string, but have no value at all (for the same reason, you can't compute 2 + _).